# How strong is Marvel's Colossus? Has his strength been consistently portrayed over the years?

Tags: marvel, colossus

How strong is Colossus? Before he became the new Juggernaut, everybody said he could lift over 100 tons. Now they're saying can lift 70 tons.

- When he was a teenager he could only lift 40 tons. However, when Colossus was a teenager, he was strong enough to knock down the original Juggernaut ([Cain Marko](https://marvel.fandom.com/Cain_Marko_%28Earth-616%29)) and if he was lifting 40 tons at that time, he wouldn't be able to do that.
- I personally believe he's a [Class 100](https://marvel.fandom.com/Category:Strength_Class) or else he wouldn't be able to go toe to toe with the heavy hitters of the Marvel Universe. Can anyone explain this discrepancy?

Comment: It makes sense that he gets stronger over time, especially from teenager to adult.

Comment: 70 tons isn't much more than an M1 Abrams tank. I would think he'd strain to lift *two* of those, but that's just me.

Comment: Of course it hasn't been consistently portrated. What *is* consistently portrayed in a long-running comic book series?

Answer (score 37):

According to the Marvel Universe Trading Card Series 2 (1991), the strength classifications are as follows:

[image]

Judging by this:

- [Sasquatch](http://marvel.com/images/gallery/story/1098/images_from_make_mine_marvel_marvel_universe_trading_cards_series_2/image/83632): 6
- [She-HulK](http://marvel.com/images/gallery/story/1098/images_from_make_mine_marvel_marvel_universe_trading_cards_series_2/image/83656): 6
- [Thor](http://marvel.com/images/gallery/story/1098/images_from_make_mine_marvel_marvel_universe_trading_cards_series_2/image/83689): 7
- [Hulk](http://marvel.com/images/gallery/story/1098/images_from_make_mine_marvel_marvel_universe_trading_cards_series_2/image/83699): 7
- [Rhino](http://marvel.com/images/gallery/story/1098/images_from_make_mine_marvel_marvel_universe_trading_cards_series_2/image/83739): 5

Colossus didn't get a card in Series 2, but did in Series 3, which used the same metric:

[image]

His strength is a 6, which puts him in the 50 to 100 ton range. Juggernaut did not get cards in either of these series, but he did get a card in the X-Men: Series 1 trading card set, published by the same manufacturer at the same time.

[image]

His strength is also a 6. And yes, [Colossus' strength is also a 6 in this series](http://images.checkoutmycards.com/zoom-back/252a59bb-bd72-4e04-9100-4f8864301740.jpg).

Comment: These cards are the first thing I thought of when I read the question. Good find!

Comment: All of these cards are over 15 years old. There is far more recent information available about the character. These would have listed his strength at the time. And not very accurately due to the limited range of the Marvel strength table.

Answer (score 32):

#### [Colossus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossus_%28comics%29) is a mutant whose powers were due to his cellular replacement of his organic structure with an extra-dimensional organic osmium steel. This allowed his body to increase his physical resilience and superhuman strength.

- Even as a teenager his superhuman strength was impressive placing him in the upper tiers of strength in the Marvel Universe at approximately 70-75 tons.
- This put his strength in the same class as [Doc Sampson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doc_Samson), [The Thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thing_%28comics%29), [She-Hulk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/She-Hulk) and [Thundra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thundra).
- Since he was still a teenager, Xavier expected his physical ability to increase as he grew older. He was expected to achieve a Class 100 status making him the equal of The Thing, The Abomination, an un-enraged Hulk or Thor (without his strength enhancing belt or gauntlets).
- His physical strength is currently greater than when he first joined the X-Men due to the realignment of his cells by Magneto following an injury during the Mutant Massacre. (X-men #188)
- While in his armored form, Colossus requires no food, water, or even oxygen to sustain himself, and is extremely resistant to injury. He is capable of withstanding great impacts, large caliber bullets, falling from tremendous heights, electricity, and certain magical attacks.

**Recently, Colossus has become an agent of [Cyttorak](https://marvel.fandom.com/Cyttorak_%28Earth-616%29), a near-immortal extra-dimensional being who is a member of a group of entities called [the Octessence](https://marvel.fandom.com/Octessence). These beings vast power is unmatched except by their mystical opposite, [the Vishanti.](https://marvel.fandom.com/Vishanti)**

[image: The Octessence]

*The Octessence trying to find a way to maintain their influence on the human world.*

- The previous agent of Cyttorak was [Cain Marko](https://marvel.fandom.com/Cain_Marko_%28Earth-616%29), brother to Charles Xavier. Marko was a normal human who was imbued with the power of Cyttorak. Cyttorak had been banished from the human realm and found a way to disguise a portion of his power in a Vietnam village.
- Cain Marko discovers the [Crimson Gem of Cyttorak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crimson_Gem_of_Cyttorak) and read the inscription: "Whosoever touches this gem shall possess the power of the Crimson Bands of Cyttorak! Henceforth, you who read these words, shall become forevermore a human juggernaut!"
- The stone gives a fraction of the power of Cyttorak to whoever possesses it via acting as a portal to or containing a portal within it to the Crimson Cosmos. The infusion of power gave Cain Marko, superhuman levels of physical strength, resistance and durability. The power increase is so vast, when the Juggernaut begins moving in a direction, he is basically unstoppable.
- The power of the Juggernaut allowed him to battle entire superhero teams to a standstill. Juggernaut fought the X-men numerous times with the best result being Marko leaving the scene of the battle. Surrounded by a mystical field of force, Marko was basically invulnerable to harm and had the strength to shatter mountains when properly motivated. Only a few beings have ever managed to stop Marko once he became unstoppable (Hulk, Skaar and Thor; a very short list).
- Now Colossus has been imbued with the power of Cyttorak. If the previous power increase is any indication, he is a far more powerful being than Cain Marko ever was. He has held his own against the Red Hulk and fought against [the Worthy during the Fear Itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear_Itself_%28comics%29) story line.

[image: Colossus the Juggernaut bringing the pain to Kuurth, Breaker of Stone]

*Colossus the Juggernaut bringing the pain to Kuurth, Breaker of Stone during Fear Itself.*

- For all intents and purposes his physical form should allow him to channel more energy from the Crimson Cosmos, giving him access to limitless physical strength. Cyttorak, even when offered a chance to remove his power from Colossus while he was possessed by the Phoenix force (which everyone expected him to do) Cyttorak refused indicating Colossus' suitability as his avatar far exceeded anyone who has ever held the title.

[image: Cyttorak on his throne in the Crimson Cosmos, his personal dimension.]

*Cyttorak on his throne in the Crimson Cosmos, his personal dimension.*

**I would expect Colossus' power now exceeds the physical strength, stamina, durability and invulnerability of all but the near-cosmic level entities such as Thor, Gladiator, the Green and Red Hulks or cosmic beings such as the Sentry, the All-father Odin or the Heralds of Galactus.**

Comment: +1, as a guy who hasn't read lots of comics about the X-Men and mainly only watched the films, I can only find this awesome. The movie version of Colossus is so dull, oh boy.

Comment: Especially the Deadpool movie version.  Loved the movie, hated the rendering of Collossus

Answer (score 7):

From [Marvel.com](http://marvel.com/universe/Colossus_%28Piotr_Rasputin%29#ixzz1mJ0t9whS)

> Colossus can transform his body tissue into an organic, steel-like substance that grants him superhuman strength enabling him to lift/press up to 75 tons and makes him impervious to most injury.

(Should be about as Canon as you get, but that doesn't mean the various writers have always agreed with the details.)

Answer (score 1):

Colossus has undergone many transformations since Professor X brought him to the state those many years ago but he has always been in the top five when it comes to potential for sheer brute force.  The only thing that has held him back form his full potential is second guessing himself or his doubts on his contribution to the team. At his peak Colossus can hold his own with any being in the Marvel Universe with the exception to beings like the Silver Surfer, Thanos, Odin, Galactus, you know beings with cosmic origins.

Answer (score 0):

Colossus was originally at 70 tons "cold," meaning he could lift 70 tons over his head without issue.  Over the years every writer of the various comics, Colossus has been in have taken some liberties.  It is written that after Magneto helped to heal Colossus, he was even more powerful.  That, in conjunction with his getting older (he was a teen when he joined the X-Men at his 70 ton strength), he has become even stronger.

Without the Juggernaut power, I would put Colossus at roughly 100 tons.  More than the Thing, less than the Hulk.  The real issue is that it is alluded that since Piotr is a pacifist by nature, he never really cuts loose.  In the comics, when he does "cut loose" he can really be formidable.  But those instances are few and far between.

With the Juggernaut power, his strength is virtually incalculable.  Potentially growing as he is moving.

Comment: "*Without the Juggernaut power, I would put Colossus at roughly 100 tons.*" What are you basing this number off of?

Answer (score 0):

According to the (Original) Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe (from the 80's), Colossus could lift (press) 70 tons.  He fought Juggernaut and lost, but held his own because of the durability of his Organic Steel form.  Juggernaut has always been "class 100" strength (on par w/ Thor & an enraged Hulk).  As a Combination Colossus/Juggernaut, his strength must well surpass the original Juggernaut's (and Thor as well, but not Hulk, who's only limit is his level of anger).  I wouldn't add 70 tons to Juggernauts strength, but you already have a Base of 70 tons (Vs. normal human strength), so maybe he's 140-150% of the Original Juggernaut's strength?

Answer (score 0):

While it may not be "canon" due to this example being in the *Ultimates* universe, I'd cite a correlation based around the similarities in portrayal of power bases between that and the 616 universe. Even the numbers [according to the wiki] seem to match up fairly, as shown here. Included is a statement about his super human strength:

[image]

This is backed up by the action of him actually **lifting a K-14 submarine** and _walking out of the water in the same comic! This can be seen here:

[image]

I attempted to find the exact weight of a K-14 for context and reference, but the closest I could come to when searching for Russian submarines was this:

> The Russian Navy deploys a ballistic missile submarine fleet consisting of four **24,000-ton Borei I class SSBNs**, six **18,200-ton Delta IV class SSBNs**, one recently overhauled Delta III class SSBN (Ryazan), and the last of the largest submarine class ever built, the giant Typhoon class Dmitriy Donskoy (TK-208)....With an estimated submerged displacement of more than **48,000 tons,** Typhoon class boats have more than twice the total displacement of the American Ohios, yet carry four fewer missiles.

This should be noted because, in this example, even if we go with one of the medium sized subs of 24,000 tons, we have to keep in mind that Piotr was *also* lifting it will under *thousands of pounds of water pressure, AND with the added water ballast it maintained!* This alone should show how powerful [this version] of the hero is, in terms of raw strength.

Granted, Colossus' power has actually *grown* over time; when he first arrived at Xavier's school in the 616 universe as a young adult/late teenager, feats at the above level where never shown. Concurrently, in later comics [decades chronologically, but in story where he was his late 20s-early 30s], he was shown being strong enough to stand up to [even if he was defeated by] an enraged Hulk, with his agility outclassing that of the monster. This can be seen here:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Now mind you, it was even stated by Peter himself that the Hulk "looked weak" and seemd disoriented here, so its unlikely he was fighting anywhere *near* his peak, as he was in  *Wolrd War Hulk*  where he broke Peter's arms in his metal form. Still, to be able to take on **any** form of the Hulk and have him at a disadvantage for even a *short* time speaks to a strength/power level that is **nothing to joke about.** And this little scuff up *did* take place in the 616 universe, so it counts as a viable display of Peter's strength.

While on this, I'm not exactly certain what the difference would be in Peter's strength between his *Ultimates* and *616* counterparts, but it should be noted that, in most cases, heroes powers and abilities seem to be fairly comparable in both worlds. The wiki quote below speaks specifically to the *Ultimates*  version, but its not inconceivable that standard Colossus is somewhere within a similar range.

> **Superhuman Strength:** Ultimate Colossus possesses vast superhuman strength sufficient to lift in far in excess of a 100 tons easily, demonstrated by his ability to lift a Russian submarine weighing thousands of tons off the sea-bed, stop an oncoming train and his resistance to Magneto's magnetic control while in his armoured form was such that he was able to overpower his control, and defeat him. He even once managed to tear Wolverine's left leg off with little effort (it should be noted that the Earth-1610 version of Adamantium is not nearly as durable as that of Earth-616). However the most incredible feat of strength that he has ever performed is when he tossed an enormously huge Sentinel hundreds of feet into the air and even managed to do that from an awkward position and while the Sentinel was applying pressure, trying to squash him.[13] He has also defeated the likes of Thor in physical combat. He is one of the physically strongest beings in the Ultimate Universe.

As to his strength being "displayed consistently", well...that's a bit more dicey. To my knowledge, *no* marvel hero has had their strengths be "consistent" throughout an entire series; on the plus side, they tend to grow over time, like any well trained skill or muscle. On the other, retcons can change reasons or rationale behind powers.  Plotwise, we have seen abilities falter or things that *shouldn't* happen to them happen, just as a result of the story needing to progress. Colossus is subject to this same happening; yes his overall powers will always remain the same, but their "extent" can depend heavily on the writer, the context, and the demands of story, plot and drama.

Generally speaking, however, I believe he has been shown to be a mutant of ever increasing [but not *unebeleivably so* unless it was something like him taking on Juggernaut's powers] but steady power growth in line with his character.