# How high can the Hulk jump?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk

The Hulk is so powerful that he can jump long distances. In fact, he can cross cities with his jumps. How high can the Hulk jump? Can he jump so high that he can reach the Moon?

Comment: Doesnt he still need to breathe ? And wouldn't his body still freeze?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**The Hulk has had the physical power to reach [escape velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity) into space in Incredible Hulk #254. But he does not continue to move. And eventually passes out due to lack of oxygen.**

[image: Hulk reaches space...]

The Hulk has numerous other jumping feats including crossing the ocean by leaping, catching fighter planes and even missiles. There are even [physics scholastic articles](http://www.wired.com/wiredscience/2012/05/the-physics-of-the-hulks-jump/) written about Marvel's Cinematic Hulk (Earth-199999) jumping prowess.

Comment: Yikes.  Having Hulk jump upward at 7+ miles/sec imparts the same energy to the ground and atmosphere as a Hulk-sized meteor strike at the same velocity.  Very, very bad for anyone the vicinity.

Comment: Only in our reality. Also, space isn't cold. Which is another difference from the MU and real life. Not to mention, he's able to speak in space.

Comment: Doesn't he jump from "Planet Hulk" into moon? He was the only one which could support the environment. I always ask myself about it, the same happens with superman, how hell does he still breath there?

Comment: If the Hulk talks in space and no one is around to hear it, does it make a sound?