# Is Colossus strong only when he transforms?

Tags: marvel, x-men

The superhuman strength of Colossus is given to him only when he transforms or does he have superhuman strength all the time?

If possible I would like answer both from comic universe and x-men movie universe

Comment: This is answered indirectly in the top 2 answers and directly in [@K-H-W's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/11007).

Comment: Maybe he only transforms when he’s strong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that he's very strong whilst in his soft state, but stronger in his organic steel state.

Perhaps more importantly, though, in his organic steel state, he is able to properly withstand the physical stresses that come with being super powered, and he can let loose.